# Store location of command button cell address to variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Okay so I'm using Excel and trying to get a cell address based off the location of the command button I'm clicking. I want to store that cell address in a variable as I click the button to be used in the next code for the user form that pops up as a result of clicking that button. Ive looked at this link: [Store location of cell address to variable in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735803/store-location-of-cell-address-to-variable-in-vba) , which is similar to what I'm trying to do but I cant seem to get it to work with the `ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address` that gives an address based off the top left corner of the command button. I'm trying to do it this way so I can use the same code from the next part for every similar button I add without having to manually change the code based off where the button is.

I'm pretty new when it comes to Excel and VBA so any help would be appreciated.

### Edit:

I tried adding the code but I'm getting a Runtime error '1004' Unable to get Buttons property of the Worksheet class. I have this

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim BtRng As Range

    Set Btnrng = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell

    MsgBox Btnrng.Address
    Btnrng.Offset(3, 3) = "Hello"
    formAddBill.Show

End Sub
```

This button is also popping up a userform for information input. the error is happening on `Set Btnrng = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using application.caller then I assume your buttons are from the forms.control toolbox. This makes life a lot easier.

### Assign each button with this code example:

```
Sub Rng_Butn_Clicked()
    Dim BtRng As Range
    Set Btnrng = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
    MsgBox Btnrng.Address
    Btnrng.Offset(3, 3) = "Hello"
End Sub
```

If you are using command buttons from the activex toolbar, it can get a bit confusing. Doing it one at a time is easy enough

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.CommandButton1.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Hi"
    Me.CommandButton1.TopLeftCell.Offset(, 2).Interior.Color = vbBlue
    MsgBox Me.CommandButton1.TopLeftCell.Address
End Sub
```

But assigning one code to many activex command buttons is not as easy, I would prefer to use the Forms Buttons if you want to assign one code to many buttons.

### Edit: If you are getting this error

[image]

You probably put the code in a command button. Please reread my answer.

### This is what I am referring to:Form Controls & ActiveX Controls

[image]

Comment: I tried adding the code you suggested but I'm getting a Runtime error '1004' Unable to get Buttons property of the Worksheet class. I have this `Sub Button2_Click()
 Dim BtRng As Range
    Set Btnrng = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
    MsgBox Btnrng.Address
    Btnrng.Offset(3, 3) = "Hello"
formAddBill.Show
End Sub` this button is also popping up an userform for information input. the error is happening on `Set Btnrng = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell`

Comment: I edited your question and added the new information. Please note in my answer I gave you two codes, one for the forms button & one for the activex button. I think you put the Forms Button code into the Activex Control.