# VBA - Store Address within loop as a new range variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a new range of a cell inside a loop, and get the following error with my current code:

> Object variable or With block variable not set

This is my code and I tried looking off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735803/store-location-of-cell-address-to-variable-in-vba) question. The error comes from the `top= ...` line

```
Private Sub test_sub()


    Dim rngReference As Range, b As Range, top as Range
    Dim top As Range

    Set rng= Workbooks("file.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Columns(1)

    For Each b In rng= 
    ' Look for cell that meets criteria
        If InStr(1, b.Text, "THIS CELL") > 0 Then
        ' Store offset of current cell as new range
            top = Range(b.Offset(1, 1).Address)

            Debug.Print b.Address; b.Offset(1, 1).Address; top 
        End If

    Next b

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of: `For Each b In rng=` did you want: `For Each b In rng.Cells` for what you seem to want to do? Otherwise it isn't going to look at each cells.

Comment: @AndrasDorko without parameters, `.Cells` is entirely redundant in a case like this.

Comment: Also, you can't legally declare `top As Range` twice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Missing `Set` (this is required when assigning values to object-type variables):

```
Set top = Range(b.Offset(1, 1).Address)
```

but would be better as

```
Set top = b.Offset(1, 1)
```

`b.Offset(1, 1)` is already a `Range` object, so no need to convert it to `Address` and then back to `Range`.